# Seeking freelance (academic) publication platforms

Tags: freelance-websites, working-from-home, proposal

Briefly speaking, I'm looking for a freelancing opportunity to write academic papers (topics related to Artificial intelligence, digital transformation, political philosophy, sociology, and literature.

I have two MA theses (one in English literature, the other in political ideas in the digital age). Are there any platforms where I can publish or find a freelancing opportunity? I need to be more visible to publish my articles or works. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

There are several academic publication platforms and freelancing opportunities that you can explore to publish your academic papers. Here are some suggestions:

Academia.edu - A platform where academics and researchers can share their research papers and get feedback from others in their field. It is free to use but offers premium features for a fee.

ResearchGate - Another platform that allows researchers to connect with others in their field and share their research papers. It is also free to use but offers premium features for a fee.

Freelance websites - Platforms like Upwork, Freelancer, and Fiverr can connect you with clients who are looking for academic writers. You can bid on projects that match your skills and interests.

Online academic journals - Many academic journals publish articles online, and some of them accept submissions from freelance writers. You can find these journals by searching for your field of interest and adding "academic journal" to your search terms.

LinkedIn - You can use LinkedIn to connect with professionals in your field and showcase your expertise. You can also search for freelance opportunities on the platform.

Remember that getting published can take time and effort. Be persistent and keep refining your writing skills. Good luck!